# strange error message fro x-debug

Tags: php, wamp, xdebug, notice

I have a PHP app which runs well. But, from time to time, I get a notice:

```
( ! ) Notice: Unknown: Skipping numeric key 0 in Unknown on line 0
```

When I view source, I have nothing, When I Inspect element, I get:

```
<font size="1">
 <table class="xdebug-error xe-notice" dir="ltr" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1">
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <th align="left" bgcolor="#f57900" colspan="5">
      <span style="background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;">( ! )      
      </span> Notice: Unknown: Skipping numeric key 0 in Unknown on line <i>0</i>
    </th>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</font>
```

This is a Windows developemnt machine + WAMP with PHP 5.4.x
How do I get rid of this message?

Comment: Do you use some array, where you could possible use 0 as index? I read some stuff where `$_SESSION[0]['someid']` and `$_SESSION['someid'][0]` were messed up causing the error.

Comment: But `Unknown on line 0` is certainly a bug in PHP. May be related to usage of some global variables.